# Error Handling in Go

Tags: error-handling, go

I have a go code like this,

```
main()
{
    do something
    do something
    .
    .
    .
    do something
}
```

Now, I don't know which "do something" is throwing an error. Is it possible in Go to catch the error and print it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go language did not include exception handling mechanism. However, it has [panic/recover](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Handling_panics) mechanism which gives a little bit of exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`recover`](http://blog.golang.org/2010/08/defer-panic-and-recover.html). Alternatively, check the return values from those functions. It's idiomatic in go to call the error value `ok`, and immediately check it.

```
meh, ok := do_something()
if !ok {
```

Comment: It's not that idiomatic to use `ok` as variable name for error. `ok` is mostly used for type assertion, but for error values `err` is more usual than `ok`.